# seek for help on java generic method

Tags: java, generics

I have following class structure,

```
abstract class AbstractA {...}
class A1 extends AbstractA {...}
class A2 extends AbstractA {...}

abstract class AbstractB<T extends AbstractA> {
  public void handle(T a) { ... }
}
class B1 extends AbstractB<A1> {
  public void handle(A1 a) { 
    super.handle(a);
    ...
  }
}
class B2 extends AbstractB<A2> {
  public void handle(A2 a) { 
    super.handle(a);
    ...
  }
}
```

Now I want to implement a generic method that would take a list of AbstractB and related AbstractA as parameters. e.g.

```
Handler.<B1, A1>handle(listOfB1, A1);
Handler.<B2, A2>handle(listOfB2, A2);
```

and

```
Handler.<B1, A2>handle(listOfB1, A2);
Handler.<B2, A1>handle(listOfB2, A1);
```

is not allowed.

I tried

```
class Handler {
  // public static <T extends AbstractB<K extends AbstractA>, K extends AbstractA> handle(List<T> list, K a) {
  public static <T extends AbstractB<? extends AbstractA>, K extends AbstractA> handle(List<T> list, K a) {
    for (T tmp : list) {
      tmp.handle(a);
    }
  }
}
```

but both does not compile. Can anyone help and give me any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to :

```
  public static <T extends AbstractB<K>, K extends AbstractA> void handle(List<T> list, K a) {
    for (T tmp : list) {
      tmp.handle(a);
    }
  }
```

Note that your method was missing a return type (I'm assuming your intended a void return type).

However, the main issue was that the type bound of `T` should be `extends AbstractB<K>` and not `extends AbstractB<? extends AbstractA>`.

Consider what happens in your current definition of the static handle method.
The current signature of the static method allows this call :

```
List<B1> listOfB1;
Handler.<B1, A2>handle(listOfB1, A2);
```

But in the body of the static method, you can't pass an `A2` instance to the handle method of a `B1` instance, which is why your code doesn't pass compilation. Therefore the type bound of T must depend on K.